# How to return Unit from a scala function?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to make a function return Unit (this is to implement an RxScala observer), but when I add `()` to the end of it, I get an error "Application does not take parameters". Here's my code:

```
val client3MessageStreamObserver: Observable[Message] = client3.messageStream()
client3MessageStreamObserver.subscribe(
  m => println("Unexpected message received by client3"),
  // callback for handling exceptions
  t =>
    println("Ex client3: " + t)
// want to make this line work (which it doesn't) which is why 
// I need to be able to return Unit. 
//        client3TestPromise.success(true)
    ()     // error after adding Unit literal here.
)
```

Why do I get this error after adding `()` and how can I get rid of it? If I leave it out I get an error saying "Type mismatch: Expected (Throwable) => Unit, actual: (Throwable) => Any)".

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
val client3MessageStreamObserver: Observable[Message] = client3.messageStream()
client3MessageStreamObserver.subscribe(
  m => println("Unexpected message received by client3"),
  t => println("Ex client3: " + t)
 () => ()
)
```

The third function `onCompleted` is a function `Unit => Unit`. So, the parameter is `()` and then in the return we can explicitly return `()` or any method returning a `()` such as `println`.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I worked this out. Because `subscribe` expects functions as it's arguments, I needed to wrap multiple instructions in braces to make a code block, i.e.:

```
val client3MessageStreamObserver: Observable[Message] = client3.messageStream()
client3MessageStreamObserver.subscribe(
  // single instruction function doesn't require braces
  m => client3TestPromise.failure(new RuntimeException("Unexpected " +
      "message received by client3")),

  // multi-instruction function does require braces
  t => {
    println("Ex client3: " + t)
    client3TestPromise.success(true)
  }
)
```

Comment: This works because you're just implementing the `onNext` and `onError` methods in the `Subscribe` trait. This is fine, if you don't want any behaviour for the `onComplete` method.

Comment: Yeah I don't need to do anything onComplete right now. It was more an issue with syntax. I couldn't work out how to pass the parameters correctly.